# kotlin's generics have to write type parameter

Tags: generics, kotlin

in java ,i defined a class

```
public abstract class AdapterItem<T extends AdapterItem> {}
```

then ,i put the data of this class to a list

```
List<AdapterItem> topics
```

and i have to deliver the "topics" to a kotlin class

and my class is :

```
class ShareDialogFragment(val mTopics: List<AdapterItem>) {}
```

but i got an error: "type argument is required". i have to change the `List<AdapterItem>` to `List<AdapterItem<out AdapterItem>>` and it's not the end. i still got the error.because AdapterItem still needs type arguement.  my solution is to replace it to `List<AdapterItem<TopicItem>>` (topicItem is the subclass of AdapterItem)

but it's worse. Anybody has a solution?

Answer (score 4):

If the generic type argument is not used in the subsequent code, you can use a [star-projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections):

```
class ShareDialogFragment(val mTopics: List<AdapterItem<*>>) {}
```

Comment: I've tried this, it doesn't work.it says parameter not compatible

Comment: Can you please provide more information? I don't see how such error would be possible in the code you posted